# Dual conditional count select while grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with the following relevant fields:

```
entity_id | grouping_id | type_id
---------------------------------
1         | 1           | 1
2         | 1           | 1
3         | 1           | 2
4         | 2           | 1
5         | 2           | 2
```

I want to select all `grouping_id` values where there are X number of type n and Y number of type m. Example of what I initially thought would work:

```
select grouping_id from t_entities
group by grouping_id, type_id
having
    count(case type_id when 1 then 1 else null end) = 2
and
    count(case type_id when 2 then 1 else null end) = 1
```

Would theoretically return all `grouping_id` values that have 2 of type 1 and 1 of type 2, but because the clause is grouping by type_id as well, I get nothing back because each group exists independently, but if I drop the group by type_id then I get aggregation errors. Is there a way to do this as a raw query without using temp tables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are on the right track with your query, however instead of grouping by `type_id` you should just be grouping by the `grouping_id`.  By grouping by the `type_id` you won't ever get something that has two different values, so your `and` clause in the `having` won't work.  You should be able to execute the following to return `grouping_id =1` as the result:

```
select grouping_id 
from t_entities
group by grouping_id
having count(case type_id when 1 then 1 else null end) = 2
  and count(case type_id when 2 then 1 else null end) = 1;
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/05be6/7)